# Circuit-Breaker status in Turbine Dashboard

Tags: hystrix

Turbine dashboard is used to aggregate Hystrix metrics stream from a cluster of nodes. The Circuit-Breaker status is displayed on the Turbine dashboard as `Open` or `Closed`.

What is the logic used for arriving at the Circuit-Breaker status *for the cluster*? Does it represent the status of the Circuit-Breakers in the majority of nodes from the cluster, or is it some other logic based on time in a state, % of nodes, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all hosts are in the Open state, then the text will be green and display Open.

If all hosts are in the Closed state, then the text will be red and display 
Closed.

If some hosts are in the Closed state then the text will go orange and display how many are in the Open state and how many are in the Closed state. 
It looks something like:

```
{Open: 1, Closed: 4}
```

The logic behind this can be seen in the source of the Hystrix dashboard [hystrixCircuit.html](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/blob/master/hystrix-dashboard/src/main/webapp/components/hystrixCommand/templates/hystrixCircuit.html#L39)